# Make a bot send a message to a text channel when somebody joins or leaves its voice channel

Tags: discord.js

I want to make my bot send a message to a text channel with who just entered its voice channel or just left its voice channel. I'm new to coding but I've tried this but it's not working.

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel;
  let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel;
  if (oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
    if (newUserChannel === bot.voiceChannel) {
      console.log("Hello");
    }
  } else if (newUserChannel === undefined) {
  }
});
```

Nothing even shows up in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that doesn't work because you're using `bot.voiceChannel`, but that doesn't exist: `.voiceChannel` is a property of [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voiceChannel), so you need to get the member first.
I would do it like this:

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  // Here I'm storing the IDs of their voice channels, if available
  let oldChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel ? oldMember.voiceChannel.id : null;
  let newChannel = newMember.voiceChannel ? newMember.voiceChannel.id : null;
  if (oldChannel == newChannel) return; // If there has been no change, exit

  // Here I'm getting the bot's channel (bot.voiceChannel does not exist)
  let botMember = oldMember.guild.member(bot.user),
    botChannel = botMember ? botMember.voiceChannel.id : null;

  // Here I'm getting the channel, just replace VVV this VVV with the channel's ID
  let textChannel = oldMember.guild.channels.get('CHANNEL_ID_HERE');
  if (!textChannel) throw new Error("That channel does not exist.");

  // Here I don't need to check if they're the same, since it would've exit before
  if (newChannel == botChannel) {
    // console.log("A user joined.");
    textChannel.send(`${newMember} has joined the voice channel.`);
  } else if (oldChannel == botChannel) {
    // console.log("A user left.");
    textChannel.send(`${newMember} has left the voice channel.`);
  }
});
```

Comment: How do I then send a message to a text channel if a user has joined?

Comment: I edited my answer. You need to first get the channel you want to send the message in, then you can use `TextChannel.send()`

Comment: last thing, how would i then get the users name that joined. newMemer.username doesnt seem to work

Comment: I edited my answer: if you want to @mention the user, use the code that's in my answer now (when you convert a `GuildMember` to a string, it becomes a mention). If you just want to use the `username`, the `tag`, or other `User` properties, just use `newMember.user` -> `newMember.user.username`, `newMember.user.tag` and so on...

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH!